# JQuery - set a variable equal to another

Tags: jquery, variables

I know...this should be stupid simple but I am new to JQuery/JavaScript and this particular situation has me stumped.  Most of what I do is plagiarized from studying snippets and just trying things over and over until I get the syntax right.

I have this line defined in a function:

```
$("#regularfee").text("25.00");
```

which of course allows me to have it displayed in my div "regularfee" in my html.  This is working no problem.

All I want to do is at a later point within the same function set a different variable equal to the first.

I fully understand just saying:
var newvar = oldvar and such...but when it is represented as above I can't seem to find the right syntax to make it happen.  I promise...I have searched for a couple of hours but have not been able to find an example that works for me...please be gentle! LOL!

Additional info:

Here is a bit more detail...

```
$("#regularfee1").text("30.00"); // this displays just fine in my <div>
$("#regularfee").text("25.00"); // this displays just fine in my <div>
var regularfee = 25;  // now *really* set the var...this is what I did not realize
var regularfee1 = 30;

// some other non-relevant code...
// I have another <div> in my html <div id=regselectedfee>
// and I have a conditional that sets regselectedfee based on the conditional

// now I want to have the <div id=regselectedfee> display its newly set value.
// How do I set $("#regularselectedfee"). ??? to show either regularfee or regularfee1 variables?
```

What is the syntax of this line to make that happen?

I hope I'm stating this a bit more clearly...

Comment: What are you trying to save in a variable?  What are you trying to do?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: please provide a more complete sample of what you are looking for

Comment: I want to set a new variable - newvar with the same value as regularfee

Comment: is it this? var x = $('#regularfee').text(); it's still not clear...

Comment: Well...  based on the code you've shown above, you aren't setting any variables.  You are setting the the context of a DIV.   You DO set variables as `var newvar = oldvar`, as you mentioned.   So we *really* need more info from you in order to answer your question.

Comment: Ya, this question doesn't make any sense at all. I don't get it...

Comment: I think what you are missing is that #regularfee is not a variable .  It's a div element.  If you want to set a variable equal to the context of that div, that's one thing.   If you want to set another page element equal to it, that's something different.

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand the proper syntax when it has all of the extra "stuff" around the variable name.  If it was just "regularfee" I know you can just say "newvar = regularfee" and that works.  As I said...I am completely new to JQuesry...I'm asking what I'm sure is obvious to you guys.  I've tried close to a dozen variations of how to do it...none work.  Do you really need to see the mistakes?

Comment: OK...perhaps this is the root of my problem... I was assuming that I was actually setting a variable regularfee with that line.

Comment: Ahh... there ya go.   #regulartree is not a variable.   It's just a locator to find the page element with id=regulartree.

Comment: @user3066388: `regularfee` isn't a variable nor a variable name.  `$` is a variable; a function.  You are calling it and passing it a string as a parameter.  It returns you an object which you act upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax: `mynewvar=$("#regularfee").text();` (assuming `$("#regularfee")` has no children elements; if it does, try `$("#regularfee:first").text()`; see the [jQuery `.text()` method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for detail).

Though it may be faster to do something like this:

```
var regular_fee="25.00",
    mynewvar;

$("#regularfee").text(regular_fee);
mynewvar=regular_fee;
```

Comment: OK...I think this is close to where I'm trying to go... I am actually setting the regular_fee to 25...not "25.00" so would any of the syntax change due to using a number instead of text?

Comment: In that case you could just do `var regular_fee=25`

Comment: @RCurtis: got what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var oldvar = "25.00";

$("#regularfee").text(oldvar);

var newvar = oldvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this

`var somevalue = 25.00;`

`$("#regularfee").text(somevalue);`

then you can change the variable value after like this

`somevalue = 30.00;`

or you can do

`var another = somevalue;`